# Is there a way to compress a JSON file with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When generating JSON document types using Terraform (e.g. for policy documents) it will default to providing nice indentation, like:

```
{
    "Version":"2021-01-27",
    "ArrayOfThings": [
        "Thing",
        "OtherThing",
    ]
}
```

However, some document types in AWS have limited sizes. Is there a way of controlling what the output formatting for the documents generated by Terraform is (i.e. not the `terraform --json` output, a step in the document itself)?

Ideally I'd like to use the Terraform provider (which has a json output) and then connect that through a minifier, so it would end up being published to AWS as:

```
{"Version":"2021-01-27","ArrayOfThings":["Thing","OtherThing"]}
```

The Hashicorp terraform rule that I'd explicitly like to use this on is the `aws_iam_policy_document` one, which has a `.json` output. Is there an equivalent `.jsonCompressed` or another Terraform rule that I can use the output of `aws_iam_policy_document` to minify the JSON output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whitespace you see in the output is just it being pretty printed and that's not sent over the wire. Can you provide a worked example where you think you should be able to fit the JSON document inside a limit but Terraform is inflating it so that it no longer fits?

Comment: The json is pretty-printed via the JSON output here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/f7e96e8b638a62668df394822a1d12e8772835e0/aws/data_source_aws_iam_policy_document.go#L216 which if you then use in an `aws_iam_policy` document as the json will be pretty-printed, which you can see in AWS' Policy Document editor.

Comment: In this case the formatting decision is being made by that particular resource type implementation in the AWS provider, so any means to override it would need to be implemented in the provider itself. I don't see any currently-implemented option for that in the schema of that resource type, but you could perhaps open an issue in the AWS provider repository to discuss the use-case and see if the team would be interested in adding a new argument to control the formatting, or to make it use compact formatting by default, or provide two different attributes as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem: loading a well-formatted JSON file and then using its minified version in my Terraform script.

The [Terraform Configuration Language](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language) functions [jsonencode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) and [jsondecode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode) did the trick:

```
minified_string = jsonencode(jsondecode(file("my-pretty-file.json")))
```

I hope it helps.